# Object coordinates

Tags: c++, qt, openscenegraph

I'm working at QT application that have a OSGWidget. How could i get coordinates of picked object in osg viewer and transfer it to QT textEdit in Dialog window. Could you give advice how to extract osg::Vec3d of selected object from viewer convert it to string and show it off? For example. I have these scene:
[image: Scene]

And when i click on add button it opens a dialog window where i have a textEdit object. Transfer coords in this editText. How could be this done? Forget to add that this cubes are imported from ads file. Probably it can help in any place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve an object's coordinates from your scene, you'll need to add new event handler to your viewer. Let's call it a `PickHandler`.

Here's a basic code that will get you started. You'll need to add the "includes" and modify it to suit your needs. (Please note that I haven't tested it. I wrote it "by memory", but if there are any errors the should be very easy to fix).

**PickHandler.h**

```
class PickHandler: public QObject, public osgGA::GUIEventHandler {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  PickHandler();
  virtual bool handle( const osgGA::GUIEventAdapter& ea,
                     osgGA::GUIActionAdapter& aa );
  signals:
    void query( osg::Vec3f );
protected:
  virtual ~PickHandler()
  {
  }

  bool pick( const double x, const double y, osgViewer::Viewer* viewer );
private:
  bool getPickedPoint( const double x, const double y, float buffer,
                     osgViewer::Viewer* viewer, osg::Vec3f& point );
};
```

**PickHandler.cpp**

```
PickHandler::PickHandler() : osgGA::GUIEventHandler()
{
}

bool PickHandler::handle( const osgGA::GUIEventAdapter &ea,
                      osgGA::GUIActionAdapter &aa )
{
    osgViewer::View* viewer = dynamic_cast<osgViewer::Viewer*>( &aa );

    if( !viewer ) {
      return false;
    }
    switch( ea.getEventType() ) {
      default:
        break;
      case osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::RELEASE: {
        if( pick(ea.getXnormalized(), ea.getYnormalized(),
                 viewer ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    return false;
}

bool PickHandler::pick( const double x, const double y,
                    osgViewer::Viewer* viewer )
{

    if( !viewer->getSceneData() ) {
      return false;
    }

    osg::Vec3f point;
    float buffer = 0.005f;

    if( getPickedPoint( x, y, buffer, viewer, point ) ) {
      emit query( point );
    }
    return false;
}

bool PickHandler::getPickedPoint( const double x, const double y, float buffer,
                              osgViewer::Viewer* viewer,
                              osg::Vec3f& point )
{
   osg::ref_ptr<osgUtil::PolytopeIntersector> intersector( 0 );
   try {
        intersector = new osgUtil::PolytopeIntersector(
                osgUtil::Intersector::PROJECTION,
                x - buffer, y - buffer, x + buffer,
                y + buffer )
        ;
    } catch( const std::bad_alloc& ) {
      return false;
    }

    // DimZero = check only for points
    intersector->setDimensionMask( osgUtil:: PolytopeIntersector::DimZero );
    // 
    intersector->setIntersectionLimit( osgUtil::Intersector::LIMIT_NEAREST );
    osgUtil::IntersectionVisitor iv( intersector );
    viewer->getCamera()->accept( iv );

    if( intersector->containsIntersections() ) {
        osgUtil::PolytopeIntersector::Intersection intersection =
             *( intersector->getIntersections().begin() )
        ;

        const osg::Vec3f& P = intersection.intersectionPoints[ 0 ];

        if( P.isNaN() ) {
          return false;
        }

        point.set( P[ 0 ], P[ 1 ], P[ 2 ] );
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm using a `PolytopeIntersector`, since I don't have any solid models, like the cessna in the OSG's example data; only a lot of points and using a `LineIntersector` (the fastest) is almost impossible to get a hit. The `Polytope` will build a frustrum volume intersects with anything in the area you have specified (with the parameters when constructing the `Polytope`).

Also, you might need to play with the parameters you send to the pick function, like the buffer size. I use `ea.getXNormalized()` and inside `pick()` an `osgUtil::Intersector::PROJECTION` value.

If you use, say an `osgUtil::Intersector::WINDOW` value, you don't need to normalize the mouse values. If you don't have any "strange" transformations in your view, most likely the `PROJECTION` value is what you need.

Last thing, this code is rather old. With newer `osg` versions, maybe some of it will be seen as deprecated. I'm not sure as I haven't updated yet my picker code.

Now, with this code, when an itersection is found, it retrieves the FIRST one and send the point values via an emit. You just have to connect this emit to your SLOT and receive the cliked point coords.

Lastly, for converting something to a string, you can use the Qt String function, `QString::number(...)`.

For example:

```
const QString x = QString::number( point[0], 'd', 6 );
```

will stringify the x-coord of the point using fixed-point format with 6 decimal places.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for examples. I'll research it and try to apply to my project

Comment: Good one. I would like to add that you need to change the `osg::Viewer* viewer` to `osg::View* viewer`, otherwise the dynamic cast won't work.

Comment: @DanielR. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll change it right now.